# NodeJs back end code structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I'm quite new to web applications and have decided to create a single page web app hosted on Heroku.

My understanding of this web app is as follows:

- Client side (AngularJs) has input text box, once button press it requests server side endpoint
- Server (NodeJs) uses data from client to call external API (e.g imgur API) and returns json
- Server processes json and responds to client with information
- Client uses server response to render user interface

### Main Concerns

- **Best practices for external API calling:** Should I have an API wrapper class that allows me to call custom methods that return specific external api calls?
- **How should I handle http error responses?:** I understand that NodeJs is async by nature and all http calls are done async as well. If there are multiple responses, error or success, how do I go about handling them all without doing a custom set of ".error()" and ."success()" methods for each call?

### Furthermore

I cannot seem to find a good reference material for a simple NodeJs back end like the one I described. Please direct me if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at this Scotch.io article for creating a Single Page MEAN Application:

[Setting Up a Single Page MEAN Application Starter Kit](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application)

Comment: Thanks! This will def help with understanding the overall structure